# How to use jQuery signature plugin in jsFiddle?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am implementing the Signature plugin in my demo. So I downloaded the plugin from [this url][1].

There demo html contains a class ie `kbw-signature` which is not applied to any elements in code. However, when I run it somehow it is applied to a given `div`. So I searched the file and there is no line where it is applied to the `div`.

**Secondly**: How to use jQuery signature plugin in jsfiddle?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Signature Basics</title>
<link type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.0/themes/south-street/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link type="text/css" href="jquery.signature.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">
.kbw-signature { width: 400px; height: 200px; }
</style>
<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="excanvas.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.signature.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#sig').signature();
    $('#clear').click(function() {
        $('#sig').signature('clear');
    });
    $('#json').click(function() {
        alert($('#sig').signature('toJSON'));
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>jQuery UI Signature Basics</h1>
<p>This page demonstrates the very basics of the
    <a href="http://keith-wood.name/signature.html">jQuery UI Signature plugin</a>.
    It contains the minimum requirements for using the plugin and
    can be used as the basis for your own experimentation.</p>
<p>For more detail see the <a href="http://keith-wood.name/signatureRef.html">documentation reference</a> page.</p>
<p>Default signature:</p>
<div id="sig"></div>
<p style="clear: both;"><button id="clear">Clear</button> <button id="json">To JSON</button></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: maybe.. in left side, in "External Resources"  add the url

Comment: where is the external url ?

Comment: you are right but where is external url .can we make external url using dropbox

Comment: check here http://190.196.69.215/~vonkenne/test/js/ is my hosting, so i will deleted those files tomorrow

Comment: Sir can you please tell me that steps how you do that hosting ..have you used ?

Comment: Because next time I will make my PC as host put file on pc make url and use that

Comment: maybe in your pc couldnt do that, but maybe you could.. what is your ip?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49281/discussion-between-user2648752-and-kraysak)